# C# template methods for template IEnumerable<T>. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, templates, c#-3.0

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

I have a base class:

```
public class BaseShowFilter {
    public int    TotalCount { get; set; }  
    public int    FromNo { get; set; }
    public int    ShowCount { get; set; }
    public string SortFieldName { get; set; }
    public bool   SortAsc { get; set; }
}
```

and a couple of ChildClasses from this base class. Then I have a few of other classes that store in (for example)

```
IEnumerable<OtherClassXXX> = ....
```

And I want to apply some filter to all of them using same method implemented in BaseShowFilter:

For example I need

```
dstList = srcList.Skip(this.FromNo-1).Take(this.ShowCount);
```

So I need implement in BaseShowFilter one function that will be accept in parameter IEnumerable and will return also IEnumerable

How can I write it? In pure C++ it will be simple as 1,2,3... but here I don't know how can it be done. Result may be something like this:

```
public class BaseShowFilter {
    public int    TotalCount { get; set; }  
    public int    FromNo { get; set; }
    public int    ShowCount { get; set; }
    public string SortFieldName { get; set; }
    public bool   SortAsc { get; set; }

    public T FilterList<T>(T SrcList) where T :IEnumerable<> {
        return srcList.Skip(this.FromNo-1).Take(this.ShowCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual way to do it:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FilterList<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.Skip(this.FromNo - 1).Take(this.ShowCount);
}
```